# change content response after routers processed the content

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 7.x and need to change content response right after controller has processed it and all middlewares are done.

I do not found any way (but i do not deep too long in kernel)
How this can be possible?

Comment: after all middleware being "done" would mean this would have to be the first middleware in the stack so its the last one to touch the response on the way out ... or you are talking about touching the `index.php` file which is what returns the response in the end and probably another way or two

Comment: i need get the content that was passed to response() at last middleware u mention, probably u right, but i've checked the response class does not have methods/props to get content

Comment: yes it has methods to get/set content

Comment: can u plz point me in the code?

Comment: `Illuminate\Http\Response` extends from `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` which has all kinds of methods for interacting with the Response

Comment: thx found it, just phpstorm & idehelper generate helpers for laravel's illuminate/http/response which is really symfonyresponse